# Write data frame to hive table in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

could you please tell me if this command could create problems with overwriting all tables in the DB:

```
df.write.option(“path”, “path_to_the_db/hive/”).mode(overwrite).saveAsTable("result_data")
```

table_name is a new table in the DB, it hasn't existed.

After these commands, all tables disappeared.

I was using Spark3 and tried to solve an error:

```
Can not create the managed table('result_data'). 
The associated location('dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/result_data') already exists.
```

I expected that a new table will be created without any issues if it doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 0):

If `path_to_the_db/hive` contains other tables, then you overwrite into that folder, it seems possible that the whole directory would be emptied first, yes. Perhaps you should instead use `path_to_the_db/hive/result_data`

According to the error, though, your table does already exist.

You can use Spark to register a temporary table in SQL code, then run `INSERT OVERWRITE` query for existing tables.